# how to put the value of an input in a set of <td>inputs</td> in a table use jquery

Tags: jquery

i have an input in a form1 and a table contains inputs2 in form 2, i want to put the value of an input1 of form1 in the array inputs2 form2 when i click on button validate, in my case, it gives the value only at the 1st inputs1 of the first row of table, knowing that the button validate hide form1 and display form2.plz help

```
<div id='form1'>
     <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <label>number day 1</label>
       <input type="text" id='input1' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 1">
       <span id='error'>Input can not blank</span>
     </div> 
           <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>dd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>ee</td>
      <td>ff</td>
      <td>gg</td>
      <td>hh</td>
   </tr>

</table>

 <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button id="hide" class="btn btn-success " type="submit">valider</button>
  </div>

</div>
<!------table2 ------>
<div id='form2'>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id='input2' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 2"></td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id='input2' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 2"></td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

code jquery for to display and hide forms and put value in inputs:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
let value = $('#input1').val();

if (value == ""){
   $('#error').show();
}else{
    $("#form1").hide();
     $("#form2").show();

     $('#input2').val(value);
 }
  });

});
```

code css

```
        <style>
    #form2{
display:none;
}
#error{
color:red;
display:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Can you provide what is your desire output?

Comment: You should not have same id for multiple DOM nodes. IDs for both of them is "input2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to put the value of input box from form1 to both the input boxes in the table.

Change id="input2" to class="input2", and change the selector in jQuery.

Here is what you need to change

```
      <div id='form2'>
     <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class='input2' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 2"></td>
        <td>rr</td>
        <td>rr</td>
        <td>rr</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class='input2' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 2"></td>
        <td>rr</td>
        <td>rr</td>
        <td>rr</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
  let value = $('#input1').val();

  if (value == ""){
     $('#error').show();
  }else{
      $("#form1").hide();
       $("#form2").show();

       $('.input2').val(value);
   }
    });

  });
```